# echo privatekey makes key invalid

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, echo, private-key

I need to copy an ssh private key to a Linux machine from a different Linux VM over ssh. I used echo `$privateKey >> ~/.ssh/id_rsa`. Echo does not understand the line breaks and add the content into one line and the key becomes invalid.

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Error loading key "/home/mobileapp/.ssh/id_rsa": invalid format
```

if i use vi to edit the file and hit enter after every line breaks then the key becomes valid and stars working. How can i make echo to copy the key properly in the file.

```
echo $privateKey >> ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: is `$privateKey` actually defined?

Comment: yes, I mentioned that i can use vi on the file which gets created and i can see the content of the file. I have figured out a way to get around. I add "\n" to every line break and then use "echo -e $privateKey >> ~/.ssh/id_rsa" and it works. But i took me almost 2-3 minutes to replace all the line breaks with "\n".

Answer (score 2):

> How can i make echo to copy the key properly in the file.

Change your script to:

```
echo $privateKey | fold -w 64 >> ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

`fold` is available on a number of platforms, like Apple BSD and Linux. The command should work just about everywhere.

RFC 1421, Privacy Enhancement for Internet Electronic Mail, says 64-characters is the limit to use. Most software can handle any line length, but some software is still sensitive to the 64-character limit.

Comment: It changed the text inside the key, now the text looks different. I tried to paste the key here but it exceeds the characters limits.